# Test call from abstract class to base class using rhino mocks

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

If have following class

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass : BaseClass
{
    public override string Test(string value)
    {
        return value == null ? value : base.Test(value);
    }
}
```

Using partial mocks I can actually test the first part of the Test-code (with value = null). Is it possible to test the fact that the call to the base class is actually done when value != null?

Comment: Could you show your mock usage?

Comment: var mock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<MyBaseClass>();
//some sort of expect
mock.Test("not_empty");
mock.VerifyAllExpectations();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do that because your Test method already overrides the base method, and no ordinary dymaic mock can intercept `MyBaseClass.Test`'s invocation of `base.Test`.

[Here's a more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293151/mocking-a-base-class-method-call-with-moq/1293536#1293536), although it relates to Moq. However, the same argument applies to Rhino Mocks, and [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921046/testing-the-internals-of-a-method-with-rhinomock-or-moq/1921254#1921254).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need to behavior-test this code and make your life hard with mocking? This looks like a good candidate for state-based testing: you provide input (value) and make assertions on the output of the method. A lot of times keeping it simple saves the day.